# Initializing a ViewController when you aren't using Nib Files

Tags: swift, storyboard

I am converting a project that use to use nib files to a project where I am using Storyboards.  The app has a home screen (HomeVC) that is loaded into a navigation controller.  When the app launches it starts a data handler that pulls rss data from a number of sources and stores them in CoreData.  In the HomeVC I was instantiating the next view in the stack (FeedVC) so that I could call a reloadData() method on it when the data handler finished downloading the feeds.  To instantiate FeedVC I wrote the following code when I set up the data handler in the HomeVC.

```
// This initializes the Feed VC for use later in the VC
    FeedViewController *view = [[FeedViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"FeedViewController" bundle: nil];
    self.feedViewController = view;
```

When the data handler finished I reloaded the table view with the following code.

```
[self.feedViewController.feedsTableView reloadData];
```

This worked well.

The new project is coded in Swift and as I mentioned is using Storyboards.  My problem is that when I call

```
self.feedViewController!.feedsTableView.reloadData()
```

The compiler tells me that it is nil.  This is understandable since I no longer have a nib to instantiate the view with.  How can I instantiate the FeedVC when I am using a Storyboard instead of nib files?

**Attempted Solution**

Here is where I named the VC.

[image]

Here is the code I entered into the method that sets up the data handler.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FeedViewController") as! FeedViewController
        self.feedViewController = vc
```

Here is my storyboard name.

[image]

Maybe the issue is the feedsTableView and not the feedViewController.  I have feedsTableView declared as an option in FeedViewController.

```
@IBOutlet weak var feedsTableView: UITableView!
```

Take care,

Jon

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to set the **Storyboard ID** in the Identity Inspector using the Interface Builder :

[image]

And then you can call the following code wherever you want to instantiate your `FeedViewController` :

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nameOfYouPut") as! FeedViewController
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work.  I show what I did above.  Maybe I made a mistake.